# Short circuit detected using Zener

Tags: zener

I'm using the circuit bellow:

- Zener to prevent the circuit from overvoltage problem.
- MOSFET P + Zener as a reverse polarity protection circuit

It does not work and I can't figure out why. When powering the circuit I detect a short circuit but the circuit operates normally once the diode D63 is unsoldered.

[image: circuit]

I want to protect the power supply form voltage above 5 V (and symmetric -5 V). By unsoldering the diode D63 protecting against overvoltage the circuit works normally.

Comment: What voltage are you powering it with? In this circuit, connecting any power more than the zener break voltage will draw too much current. The zener can only limit the voltage if there is a suitable resistor in series with the power (not a good idea for this circuit).

Comment: at the very least, put the  D62 *after* the fuse F1 – that way, an overvoltage that can source enough current to fry the Zener can be stopped by the opening of F1.

Comment: Also, in reverse polarity, D62 is already normally conducting, and D61/Q61/R61 do nothing useful.

Comment: A common choice for OVP is the TL431. It's like an adjustable Zener ranging from 2.5 to 36 V. It's much more precise than a regular Zener and in itself can shunt up to 100 mA.

Comment: Does D63 measure as shorted when unsoldered?  Maybe it is bad, or installed backwards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: - D62 is a TVS Diode                                                                                                                - The voltage powering the circuit: 5V-5A                                                                                    - D63 causes a short circuit                                                                                                                                                                                                               - have you other solutions to protect the circuit from overvoltage?